# 3rd time getting stuck at "Building a ROS Package"

Tags: ros, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Before I get to this section if I do a:

```
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

i get two paths:

```
/home/ju78iklo9/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
```

But

By the time I get to Building a ROS Package and work down to:

```
catkin_make
```

I get the following output (for three complete beginning to here retries):

```
Base path://home/ju78iklo9/catkin_ws
Source space: //home/ju78iklo9/catkin_ws/src
The specified base path //home/ju78iklo9/catkin_ws contains a CMakeLists.txt but catkin_make must be invoked in the root of workspace
```

I  have a killer ROS robot design but now I find myself repeating the same elementary ROS learning steps.

Now, again, for the 4th time (due to lab distractions)

Any help is appreciated as the non-industrial robot I intend to help design & build, although it would not likely be used at Starbucks to serve drinks, would likely help ROS (& community organizations) become a household name.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

John

Note: The only path result I get after I get to Building Your Package and entering

```
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

is:

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/share
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277210/3rd-time-getting-stuck-at-%22building-a-ros-package%22/) by [ju78iklo9](https://answers.ros.org/users/32592/ju78iklo9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-12-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2017-12-03**:
I don't quite understand your question, but perhaps this will help: #q221538.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-03**:
Are you referring to the "official" [Building a ROS Package](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages) tutorial?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-03**:
I agree with @clyde. What exactly is the question? There's a lot going on here but no clear question.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-03**:
Also, what directory are you running `catkin_make` from? It needs to be in the root of your catkin workspace, i.e., `~/ju78iklo9/catkin_ws`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-04**:\

> The specified base path //home/ju78iklo9/catkin_ws contains a CMakeLists.txt [..]

and it shouldn't.

Check to make sure there is one. If there is, how did it get there?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-04**:
@ju78iklo9: As @gvdhoorn pointed out, the root of your workspace should **not** contain a CMakeLists.txt. You may want to recreate your workspace following the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @ju78iklo9 ,

as mentioned in the comments, this happens because you have the `CMakeLists.txt` on the root folder of the workspace. In your case,  `/home/ju78iklo9/catkin_ws/CMakeLists.txt`

The main `CMakeLists.txt` of the Workspace must be on the `~/catkin_ws/src/` folder, in your case, `/home/ju78iklo9/catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt`

You problem is probably on the creation process of the workspace.

If you want to create a workspace from zero, you can do the following:

1. Rename the current `~/catkin_ws` to  `~/old_catkin_ws` with:

---

```
mv ~/catkin_ws ~/old_catkin_ws
```

2. Create the new catkin_ws from zero with:

---

```
cd
mkdir catkin_ws/src -p
cd catkin_ws/
catkin_make
```

3. The ROS Packages you create must be on `~/catkin_ws/src`, so, if you want create a package named `example_pkg` that depends on `roscpp` package, for example, you would do the following:

---

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src/
catkin_create_pkg example_pkg roscpp
```

4. To compile the `example_pkg` package, you run:

---

```
cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_make
```

That is it.

If you prefer to watch a video for a better understanding, I've created [one here](https://youtu.be/U3w_ZvaIYmI).

Ruben.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0